# Confirmation of previous employment

Tags: background-check

So I got an email from my HR this morning.

> Hi Adil,
>
> The check has indeed been completed.  City of Milford records disagrees with the information you provided.  They have you working there from 2020 to 2021 while you entered 2019. Would you please confirm when you worked there?
>
> Thanks

Is there something that I should be concerned about I told her I got the dates mixed up and there was a typo on my part.

Comment: Did you start near the beginning of 2020? Is it possible you signed on in December 2019? Really, you could just say, yes, it was 2020. But if there is some reasonable explanation you could add that too.

Comment: They want to clear up the discrepancy. When did you actually work there?

Comment: Not sure what concerned means. You should continue to search for alternative jobs as you should be doing until you have a signed offer.

Comment: Voting to close, since we cannot know whether you should be concerned, we can not know how the company will react or how big your lie actually was.

Comment: So did you tell her you worked there three years instead of two?

Comment: It’s all cleared up guys were good now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not really, it wasn't like you told a massive lie. (even though 0 and 9 are opposite ends of the keyboards :S )

Just try and be careful with this sort of stuff; as first impressions are often long lasting.

I'm guessing it would be HR sorting this and not your new manager so I wouldn't go worrying about it.

Answer (score 1):

Don't worry too much about it at this point.

It doesn't look like the company wanted to reject you instantly right after they saw the mismatching information from the background check. Because if they had wanted to reject you right away, they would have sent you a rejection letter, which is not the case.

They are giving you a chance to explain the discrepancy. There could be some outcomes:

1. It could just be a simple typo, and they may be OK with it.
2. If the difference is only a few weeks of working time, they may be OK with it.
3. If the experience you earned from working for "The City of Milford" is not super critical to your job at this new company, they may be OK with it.

Honestly, at this point, we don't know how they would decide in the end regarding your application.

So, other people already give you the best advice:  **Please continue your job search until you get the **official **offer letter** signed by the company**.**

In other words, just relax and carry on with your job search. You will be fine in the end. Best of luck.